# SPFx section layouts

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts, spfx-tooling, spfx-extensions

Currently I have an issue building an SPFx solution where I'd like to create a two-column proportional section that is full-width in a modern page.

With the tools currently available to me, all I can do is make an SPFx web part with two columns that can be placed in a full-width column. However, I want to be able to place web parts in the columns.

There are several two-column section layouts, but none stretch to fill the screen - they are all limited to a max-width.

I'd like to create (or fake, if I have to) my own section layout block. How do I do this?